# Migrating Crystal Reports from 2010 to .Net Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

We have a requirement of **migrating an application built in Visual studio 2010 to Visual studio 2017**. The plan is to use **.NET Core 2.0 
for new application**. The existing application has some crystal reports created using SAP Crystal Reports for Visual 2010. Client wants to port the reports to the new application but they want to use Crystal Reports 2010 and do not want to upgrade.

So, please let me know whether we can create the application in Visual studio 2017 with Core and still use Crystal Reports 2010. If yes, please provide some information on how we can achieve it.